# Num Docs is not updating in SOLR admin UI page

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrnet, solrcloud

I have app sending update request to solr, but the commit option is handled in solrconfig.xml and the auto commit is to 15000 MS . Now problem is the Num Docs in UI page is not updating and even if i give search request none of the documents are visible could anyone let me know how to check whether my autocommit is working or not.

Once i restart the solr the number of documents will be reflected and i will be able to search. Will the ideal case be the same everytime do we need a solr service restart for autocommit to get effect ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you send the update requests?

Comment: Through SolrJ client

Comment: Do you commit the documents? i.e. both:
solr.addBeans(yourBeans);
solr.commit();

Comment: No commit Just solr.addbeans() the commit is taken care by solr Autocommit feature.

Comment: I suppose you don't have openSearcher set to false?

Comment: Yup  i have set opensearcher to false , what will happen if i have set it false ? but for committing the  index we don't require open searcher as true right, i thought openSearcher is used for making the index available for searching. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: You are right, you don't need to open a new searcher in order to commit, but you do need to open one to search the docs. In the admin panel, choose your core from the dropdown -> Plugins -> Core -> Searcher and check how many documents show once you've issued a commit, and not opened a new searcher and after opening a new searhcer.

Comment: I have one more doubt if am passing the Solr.addbeans() & Solr.Commit() together through the SolrJ client. the return status which is returned is it after the commit or before the commit.  ?

Comment: I think showing the number of docs in the interface still requires some kind of search. See the accepted reply here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293812/solrj-and-auto-commit . Does that help?

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the soft commit in your solrconfig.xml file. This makes the added documents available to search. Soft commits are light weight, set it to 2000 milliseconds.